# developers гугл api net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

Добрый день. Пытаюсь вставить в проект гугл карту. Сам код отрабатывает но что то не так с get запросами [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
require(['https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCtSFwATUb4p2pSC9QEmbERxq5QmV9IjbM'], function () {
      var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 4,
        center: uluru
      });
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: uluru,
        map: map
      });
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Видимо дело было в том, что запускал на локальном сервере `localhost:8000`.
Когда выложил тестовую версию на тестовый сайт с внешним адресом, то все заработало.

Comment: А куда вы его выложили? Ссылка не действительна.

Comment: @0xdb  На тестовый сайт заказчика, там все равно логин и пароль необходим для входа поэтому ссылку и не кидал